# how to make separate achievements

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4, game-center

I have achievements in game Center for my iPhone but my app is universal so am making achievements for the iPad i don't want them to be displayed with the iPhone achievements i want them both to be seperate

```
  -(void)checkAchievements6
 {
 if(score>10000)//achievement for getting 10000 points.
  {
    GKAchievement *achievement= [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"5Digit"];
    achievement.percentComplete = 100.0;
    achievement.showsCompletionBanner=YES;
if(achievement!= NULL)
{
    [achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error)
     {
         if(error != nil){
             NSLog(@"Achievement failed");
         }
         else 
         {
             NSLog(@"Achievement Success");
         }

     }];
}
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are asking, but could it be something like this?

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    //iPhone achievement code
} else {
    //iPad achievement code
}
```

Comment: ok i will try it but in the game centre app is there a way not to see the iPhone achievements on the iPad and vice versa